# Ionic Angular: How can I pass a variable in FormBuilder.group()?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Is it possible to pass a variable that comes via API into the formbuilder group so it is included in the POST to my server? Here is what I have so far:

```
formAPICode: any;


  ngOnInit() {
this.ionicForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  apiKey: [this.formAPICode], // This is where the API Key should be appearing but doesnt. Console log returns NULL
  name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
  email: [
    '',
    [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern('[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+.[a-z]{2,3}$'),
    ],
  ],
  mobile: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[0-9]+$')]],
  street: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
  unit: [],
  city: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
  state: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
  zip: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
  summary: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
  dateTime: [],
  existingCustomer: [],
  customerConsent: [Validators.required],
});

// Loads WP Company Data
this.wpService.postCompInfoDetails().subscribe((data) => {
  this.companyDetail = data;
  this.formAPICode = this.companyDetail.acf.forms_api_key;
  console.log(this.formAPICode); // returns 45678451-1124d-45ae-bf15-ABC
});
```

}

Here is the console JSON

```
form data {"apiKey":null,"name":"John Doe","email":"john@doe.com","mobile":"1324567894","street":"1234 Main St","unit":"Suite 202","city":"New York","state":"NY","zip":"10001","summary":"Description of summary","dateTime":null,"existingCustomer":null}
```

if i change formAPICode to this it works fine. When I introduce the API Key via external API it doesn't

```
formAPICode = '45678451-1124d-45ae-bf15-ABC';
```

Comment: Why the negative on question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're assigning `formAPICode` value to your form control **before** it gets any value. Then, when you actually get the value from the API, you're updating the `formAPICode` property but the form control already got the initial value.

Try this:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.ionicForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  apiKey: [], // You could leave this blank since we haven't gotten data from API. We will insert it later
  // ...your other inputs as normally...
});

// Loads WP Company Data
this.wpService.postCompInfoDetails().subscribe((data) => {
  this.companyDetail = data;
  this.formAPICode = this.companyDetail.acf.forms_api_key;

  // Now that we actually have the value from the API, we can patch that into the form like this
  this.ionicForm.patchValue({ apiKey: this.formAPICode });

  console.log(this.ionicForm.value) // Should print the entire form value with the actual apiKey that we got recently
});
```

Comment: Thanks man! That worked. I was not aware of patchValue in Angular.